# Backbone inserting model to collection, then updating on save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

First, I'm n00b in backbonejs.

I'm trying to build contact application similar to iPhone Contacts on iOS 7. I'm having problem to wrap my mind around it.

I have contact model like this.

```
var ContactItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/contact/',

   parse: function(response) {
       var phonesJSON = response.phones;
       var phonesCollection = new Phones(phonesJSON);
       response.phones = phonesCollection;

       // emails, addresses, etc the same way as Phones collection above
       return response;
   },

   defaults: {
       "id": null,
       "avatar": "default.png",
       "first_name": "",
       "last_name": ""
   }

});
```

Scenario is:

When I click **+ Add new phone**, a row with select box and text field is inserted. Fill in a phone number, then click *Save*, this.model.save() is called.

[image: Add new contact]

**The problem**

- If I add new Phone model to collection I'm having a problem updating that model later when I click *Save*
- If on **+ Add new Phone** I don't add model to collection, how can I add it later (how to know what to add) ?!
- When I edit fields, the underlining model properties / collections are not modified "in real time". I need some kind of connection between form text fields and Backbone model

Please give me a hint "backbone way" of doing this.

Comment: What's your server response ?

Comment: I don't have problems with server, I have a problem on the client side, the order of operations.
My current ugly sollution is using jquery $.post to send $('#form-contact-edit').serialize() to POST data to server. I want to do it via this.model.save()